# How to change bars' outline width in a displot?

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization

I managed to make a *displot* as I intended with seaborn and the only thing I want to change is the bars' outline width. Specifically, I want to make it thinner. Here's the code and a sample of how the dataframe is composed.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

data_final = pd.merge(data, data_filt)

q = sns.displot(data=data_final[data_final['cond_state'] == True], y='Brand', hue='Style', multiple='stack')
plt.title('Sample of brands and their offering of ramen styles')
```

I'm specifying that the plot should only use rows where the *cond_state* is True. Here is a sample of the *data_final* dataframe.[image: Sample here.]

Here is how the plot currently looks like.

[image: Sample here.]

I've tried various ways published online, but most of them use the deprecated distplot instead of displot. There also doesn't seem to be a parameter for changing the bars' outline width in the seaborn documentation for *displot* and *FacetGrid*

Comment: So you've tried passing e.g. `linewidth = 0.25` to the `sns.displot()` function and nothing happens?

Comment: @jared_mamrot Wow this is embarrassing, that was it! Where is that parameter listed? I read through the displot documentation in seaborn.pydata.org and it wasn't there. Damn now I just want to delete this question.

Comment: Not embarrassing at all - it's not in the docs. Probably don't delete the question because someone else might have the same issue and the answer isn't immediately obvious using the 'standard' troubleshooting steps (i.e. check the docs for the answer works 95% of the time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation for the seaborn displot function](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html) doesn't have this parameter listed, but you can pass [matplotlib axes arguments](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot.html), such as `linewidth = 0.25`, to the seaborn.displot function to solve your problem.